# Alternating headers

Tags: sharelatex

I would like to have headers on my text which alternate from page to page. So for instance, I would like to have on page 2, name of the authors and date, and on page 3, name of the conference and title of the hand-out. I tried the following but does not come out correct and also the text overlaps with the header:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[LE]{\fontsize{10}{12} 
\selectfont \ti{NA}} \fancyhead[RE]{\fontsize{10}{12} \selectfont NA} \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} \fancyhead[LO]{\fontsize{10}{12} \selectfont \ti{NA}} 
\fancyhead[RO]{\fontsize{10}{12} \selectfont 20 November 2016} \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
```

Comment: What is your document class?

Comment: What about page 4 onward? Or is your reference to 2 and 3 similar to even and odd?

Comment: My document class is article. I was referring to even and odd pages.

Answer (score 1):

`article` doesn't have right (odd) or left (even) pages by default. They are all right pages because the class assumes the document is single-sided. However,

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
```

overrides this default and permits the use of different headers, footers etc. for odd and even pages.